# In iOS 11 the backgroundcolor and textcolor of UITextFields doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, xamarin, uitextfield, textcolor

Setting the BackgroundColor and TextColor of a UITextField does not work anymore in Xamarin 11.0 on iOS 11. I don't know if it's iOS or Xamarin that breaks this functionality.

I tried setting the view.BackgroundColor the view.Layer.BackgroundColor but nothing seems to make a difference.

[image]

Version information:
Xamarin   4.7.9.45 (bd7e3753c)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android SDK   7.4.5.1 (fb018c5)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.0.0.0 (152b654)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Comment: I am having the same issue in a native Swift 4 application after an upgrade to iOS 11.

Changing the UITextFields textInputView.backgroundColor as well as the text fields backgroundColor gave me the expected result.

I'm not sure why this is happening though.

Comment: I found the problem. Possibly the TextField in iOS 11 has been changed to have different subviews. Our recursive routine also colors subviews unless we stop it at the root level of the view we want to color. After adding the code for stopping at the root level colors were good again.

Comment: B.T.W. changing the TextInputView.BackgroundColor did not solve the problem for us.